# sql server - can a single data row be split into multiple pages

Tags: sql-server, indexing, paging, sql-server-2016, usage-statistics

I'm looking into Index Operational Statistics SQL Server 2016 report. One of the columns is named "# Locks" with two subcolumns, "Row" and "Page".

As per the report my Primary Key index has Locks on 350,000 rows and on 2.2 mln pages.

My understanding that 350,000 row were split between 2.2 mln pages.

So, can we split a single table data row into multiple pages?

Comment: Thanks for the you comment squillman! I would except it as an answer to my question, if you are willing to post your comment as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server page size is 8KB, so if your row's data is larger than that it will definitely be split across multiple pages.  SQL Server does this automatically.

For further reference you can read this:
[Understanding Pages and Extents](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190969(v=sql.105).aspx)